# Proguard is not removing Log calls

Tags: android, proguard

When compiling my app using Ant I can see the verbose Proguard output, and I have things setup to remove the log statements (see below), but when I run the release apk all the log statements I was trying to remove are there.

I have 2 projects each of which include a common project. The 2 main projects and the common project each have a proguard.cfg file, all of which contain the snippet to remove log statements.

Is there something that I am missing?

** All my log statements are Log.d(...)

## proguard.cfg

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dontobfuscate
-forceprocessing
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

Comment: Just double checked as you had me worried. I definitely see none of my Log.d o/p for the Ant release build. I'm filtering Logcat o/p by its PID and I just see the dalvik GC_CONCUURRENT stuff

Comment: I have this issue. I run Proguard 4.4

Answer (score 4):

Here your proguard file is ok, but there is a detail that you may be missing.

In your gradle file you probably have something like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Check the `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android')`, so if you intent to optimize it, you should change it to `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')`.

I spent some time to realize it, saw your question but still not able to remove my `Log` calls on my code.  So I've found this link that explains that is necessary to change to the optimize file to proguard be able to optimize.

https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#enabling-gradle

Comment: proguard-android-optimize.txt fixed it for me ! 
Thanks for the explanation - you definitely deserve a Beer for that !

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `assumenosideeffects` without Proguard optimization.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of deleting or commenting out all of your log messages using pro-guard you could do something like this. Create a utility class that is basically a wrapper around the android logging system

```
public class Util{

    public static boolean showLogs = true;
    public static String myTag = 'My Tag';

    public static void logD(String message){
        if (Util.showLogs)      
            Log.d(myTag, message);
    }
}
```

**Before** I compile my app for distribution I simply call `showLogs = true;` and then all log messages are supressed

You can easily extend this class to allow you to specify the tag and produce more than debugging messages.

Comment: I have to disagree here. I rely on an identical assumenosideeffects statement to remove Log lines from my project and it works - I get no log o/p in Ant release builds. The only differences between my proguard.cfg and this one are I have only the one project and I don't state -dontobfuscate or -forceprocessing

Comment: @NickT: I removed the two items that you mentioned you don't have in your proguard.cfg file, but I still see the log statements. It was worth a try.

Comment: @slayton: according to the Proguard docs the `assumenosideeffects` will remove calls to methods that don't appear to have side effects matching the class specifications.  http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

Comment: This will not be the same result. You are still doing String concatenation here while removing the code will not.